# a query string into a structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, lucee, taffy

I am using taffy and am passing an unknown query string to a function. I do not know the query string values passed in advance, so I am trying to use that in the function but it is not working. Please point me to right direction.

Here is my code:

```
<cffunction name="qrystringToStruct" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="myStruct" default="#structNew()#" type="struct">
    <cfargument name="str" required="true" default="">
    <cfscript>
        for(i=1; i LTE listLen(arguments.str,'&');i=i+1) {
        structInsert(myStruct, i, listGetAt(arguments.str,i,'&'));
        }
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn myStruct>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getCourseById" taffy:verb="get" taffy:docs:hide>
  <cfargument name="structurl" type="any" default="" />
  <cfdump var="#structurl#">
 <cfdump var="#qrystringToStruct(structurl)#" abort> 
  <cfset var local = {} />
```

This is how I am calling the url:

```
http://localhost:9002/taffy/index.cfm//coursesMethods?credits=3&coursetitle=power
```

but all I am getting is `[empty string]`

Comment: Silly question. What is wrong with the `url.*` struct? It automatically changes the http query string into a struct.

Comment: @JamesAMohler good question.  However, from the way his question is written, it sound like he doesn't know or can't predict the url structure keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just preface this by saying I've never used Taffy.  However with that said, I don't think it's relevant to the problem specified in your posted question.  There are a few things in your code that's puzzling to me.

- Your call `qrystringToStruct(structurl)` passes one parameter but your function definition has two parameters.
- Why would you declare `myStruct` as a parameter and then `<cfreturn myStruct>` in your `qrystringToStruct` function definition?  It makes no sense.
- You say you pass the full url to `http://localhost:9002/taffy/index.cfm//coursesMethods?credits=3&coursetitle=power`?  Why not just pass the querystring portion using `cgi.QUERY_STRING`?

Anyhow, I think you're overcomplicating this and you don't need a custom function to parse out your querystring.  All you need is one line of code.

```
<cfset qryString = listToArray(cgi.QUERY_STRING, "&")>
```

You can test it out here **[here](https://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/fde8c90c75515ca62ec902165eb4dabc/acf11)**.

Comment: Hi, Ok Thanks but i think i missed the query which i had written to Loop over the the structure in a query command, that was liettrally my mitake while posting the question, i missed it. Here is the query I am trying to do: `<cfoutput>
  select * from course 
    where 1=1 
 <cfloop collection="#arguments.structurl#" item="kk">
  OR #kk# = "#trim(arguments.structurl['k'])#
 </cfloop>
 </cfoutput>`

Comment: I changed the function to this: `<cffunction name="QueryStringToStruct" output="false">
 <cfargument name="QueryString" required="yes" type="string">
 <cfset myStruct = StructNew()>
  <cfloop list="#QueryString#" delimiters="&" index="i">
   <cfset QueryStringParts = ListToArray(i, "=")>
   <cfset structInsert(myStruct, Trim(QueryStringParts[1]),Trim(QueryStringParts[2]))>
  </cfloop>
 <cfreturn myStruct />
</cffunction>` and i had the fiddle here for the one you created: https://trycf.com/gist/f745d2f9258b392ad64a16b369ffe954/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: @JJK Ok, after comparing what you were trying to do in your original post vs your updated gist, now I can see what you're doing.  Again, you are overcomplicating things.  You're recreating ColdFusion built-in functionality.  What you need is already in the `url` scope as originally mentioned by James Mohler.  Try this to verify `<cfdump var="#url#">`.  No need for a custom function.

Comment: @JJK - Please edit your question and *append* the current code, so it's clear what you're actually trying to do. That said 1) James and user9263373 are  probably correct that you don't need to create a structure of parameters - you already have one: the `URL` scope. 2) **Never** use raw client values in a SQL query. It's a sql injection risk. 3) Functions should always `local` scope function variables, including loop indexes, to avoid threading problems.